# I saw a small deer lying down in the middle of the road. ('lying' is attributive or objective complement?)

Tags: participial-adjectives

> I saw her cross the street. I saw her crossing the street.[both cross and crossing are object complements]

I wonder if the 'lying' in the sentence "I saw  a small deer lying down in the middle of the road."
is used as an attributive usage as an adjective modifying a small deer or it could be an object complement?

Answer (score 1):

> *I saw her* [*cross the street*].
>
> *I saw her* [*crossing the street*].

No: although "her" is the object of "saw", "cross the street" and "crossing the street" are not object complements. They are non-finite clauses functioning as complement of "saw".

> *I saw a small deer* [*lying down in the middle of the road*].

Here, the bracketed participial clause is modifying "small deer" in noun phrase structure. The meaning is similar to the relative clause in "I saw a small deer *that lay down in the middle of the road*".

Comment: [that was lain] should be [that was lying]. In my culture, the subject(here object) of 'cross/crossing' is her, so we learn cross/crossing is an object complement(bare infinitive or present participle) in case of the verbs of perception like see, hear, watch, feel, etc.

Comment: @BEBYGONES I don't know what you mean by "my culture", but in English grammar, "crossing the road" has no overt subject. "Her" is the syntactic object of "saw" but only the _understood_ (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause. Object complements are either adjective or noun phrases, not clauses.

Comment: I learned that 'a clause must have one subject and one verb' in my culture. My culture means in our country.

Comment: Non-finite clauses are almost always grammatically subjectless, though they have a semantic (undertstood) subject. "Cross/crossing the street" is a non-finite clause.

Comment: A matter of grammar 'terms'. Yeah, I understand your explanation now.